# Handle a "tap" from VoiceOver on a custom view

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am reviewing our app to make it more accessible, and I have a problem with a custom view. Note: I'm using Xamarin/C#, but this hopefully does not change anything, since it's using the same API under the hood.

This custom view basically mimics the "slide to unlock" gesture. This of course does not work with VoiceOver since when it is enabled, the user cannot "slide" but only double tap to activate a view/button.

The view is as `UIView` subclass, composed of children `UIVIew`s, and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that catches the gesture from left to right.

I started by adding accessibility info to the parent class:

```cs
IsAccessibilityElement = true;
AccessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTrait.Button;
AccessibilityLabel = "...";
```

VoiceOver now correctly sees the slider as one view, instead of checking the subviews. However, I cannot activate it using the "VoiceOver double tap" gesture.

I tried subclassing `UIControl` instead of `UIView` and overriding [sendAction()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618237-sendaction), but this method is not called.

I don't want to set the `UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction` trait to the control, because this goes against rendering the app accessible.

What can I do to be able to catch the "double tap" and do the action that's supposed to be done when the user slides the control ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... This was a Xamarin problem after all.

To make sure VoiceOver works with custom controls, you have to conform to the [UIAccessibilityAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibilityaction) **informal protocol**. In my case it was [accessibilityActivate()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615165-accessibilityactivate).

But since I am using Xamarin, I needed to *export* the method, to make sure that the runtime could see that I implemented a method from the informal protocol.

```cs
[Export("accessibilityActivate")]
public bool AccessiblityActivate() {
  Console.WriteLine("It works!");
  return true;
}
```